# possible to run createDocumentFragment in node.js?

Tags: node.js, dom, document

I'm trying to run some javascript code (originally developed for browser) in node.js environment.

I use createDocumentFragment in order to minimize the node access.
(Obviously it is to create Dom elements in the document body)

I can run $.append using cheerio as $ in node.js.
Is there a way to run `createDocumentFragment` in node.js?

Answer (score 0):

*No* because **node.js** initializes it in jscript not in **DOM**